# Installing Oracle XE 11.2 on Centos 7

Tags: oracle11g, centos7

This is my first time installing Oracle XE and I am struggling. I have finally gotten through the configure script but get the following error:

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done  
Configuring database...  
Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details
```

When I check the log files in the above mentioned directory I see these errors:

```
ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER  
ORA-00130: invalid listener address '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain-efw)(PORT=1521))'
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

What I haven't said is this is a Centos 7 vm running on VirtualBox. What else can I provide to help?

TIA...

Answer (score 0):

a) Verify whether the host name, **localhost.localdomain-efw** is correct and is resolving to VM's IP.  If not replace with correct VM host name or VM IP.
b) Verify whether the VM hostname and IP entry are in /etc/hosts file. If not add entries.
c)edit ./bash_profile of oracle user, as follows:
(replace the content within tags <> for your environment)

```
# Oracle Settings
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR

ORACLE_HOSTNAME=<hostname.domainname>; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=<DB11G>; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=</u01/app/oracle>; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE</product/11.2.0/db_1>; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=<DB11G>; export ORACLE_SID

PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH
```